# Why does my Hotmail account appear under 'On my computer' folder in Outlook 2011 for Mac?

Tags: macos, microsoft-outlook, hotmail

Why does my Hotmail account appear under 'On my computer' folder in Outlook 2011 for Mac, whereas my Gmail account auto-configured itself with its own set of folders?

Worse still, if you select 'Hide 'On my computer' folders in Preferences, then you don't see your Hotmail at all.

Can this be fixed? I want Hotmail to have its own folders just like Gmail.

Comment: Did you configure Hotmail as POP, Google as IMAP?

Comment: I didn't seem to get a choice using the autoconfigure in Macbook Air...however I believe POP3

Comment: If you respond to comments, add @username (e.g. @Daniel) to your response. That way, the other user gets a notification just like the one you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your Hotmail account is configured to use POP, in which case Outlook is downloading copies of your messages and storing them locally on your computer.  If it configured Gmail on its own, it most likely configured it as IMAP, and that's what you're seeing.  Last I checked I don't believe Hotmail offers IMAP access to your account, so you're stuck using POP with Hotmail.